# Team Services - Create issue in Github on failed build

Tags: github, azure-pipelines, workitem, azure-pipelines-build-task, build-agent

I am using Github as my repo as well as my Kanban/Scrum board. We use Visual Studio Team Services for our automated builds. We really like the way VSTS works and it works well with Github as the repo.

However, I want to be able to create a new Github issue/bug if and when our Continuous Integration build fails. I know you can create a VSTS Work Item but I would rather keep all issues centralized.

Is there any way to hook up VSTS to create a Github repo whenever a build fails? Or perhaps create a Github issue whenever a new VSTS Work Item is created?

We are running our own build server so possibly something can be done on that end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a github issue when VSTS build failed with two options.

#### Option1:

In VSTS build definition, **add a powershell task in the end of the build process**. Functions in the powershell should include:

1. Detect above build tasks in the build definition. Use [REST API timeline](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#timeline) to get build detail, you can find each task result in `result` parameter.
2. Determine to create a github issue or not. If all above build tasks are pass to build, don’t create github issue. Else, [create a github issue by github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue).

#### Option2:

Create your own website, and in VSTS use **web hooks** to tigger build fail information for your own website. After your own website receive the build information, it can create a github issue.

Comment: How would you detect that individual build tasks have failed? We are doing MSBuild and also running command line and batch files.

Comment: You can use REST API **timeline** to get build details https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds#timeline, then you can find each build task result in **`result`** parameter.